# Send file back in a readable format?

Tags: c#, javascript, forms, file, rest

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this. Much to my chagrin, I realized that browsers such as IE8 and IE9 do not support any type of file reader.

So after a bit of research, I'm trying to have the server read the contents of the file, convert it to base64, and then send it back down to the client where the javascript takes it from there.

Is this possible? How would you recommend doing this?

For example right now I have set up a RESTful service that gets the file once the form is submitted...

```
public string Post()
    {
        string readableFile="";
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        var httprequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httprequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httprequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httprequest.Files[file];
                //convert to base64? somehow?
            }
        }
        return readableFile;

    }
```

the postedFile variable contains the file information, I would just need to make it into a readable format...though, I am having difficulty.

Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"do not support any type of file reader"` What type of file are we talking about? You can't possibly expect a browser to support every type of file under the sun, can you?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: refers to the HTML5 FileReader() interface, not just a generic concept of parsing some files. afaik, FileReader can open any file, even one larger than the RAM of the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpPostedFile` class has an `InputStream` property which you can use to read the data.  To covert that data to a base64 string you could do the following:

```
public string Post(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    if (file.InputStream.Length > Int32.MaxValue) // Or some other file length limitation
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    int length = (int)file.InputStream.Length;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];

    file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);

    string encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

    return encodedString;
}
```

You have to code it significantly differently if you want to support larger files over 4GB, but I'm assuming you want to set a reasonable limit on the file size to avoid getting an out of memory exception or having to cache the file to a hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for C#, right?

```
string sixtyfour = System.Convert.ToBase64String(
                       myFileUploadControl.FileBytes,
                       0,
                       myFileUploadControl.FileBytes.Length);
```

That should take the contents of a fileupload control and put it into base64.